# WordPress filter category page of A to Z

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a little problem stupid but I can not find the solution. 
I explain you, I created a page where I put all the categories of my site, I created above of categories a line with all the letters of the alphabets, I would like when I click on a letter the alphabet, all category starting with the letter selected will appear.
For example, if I select the letter J all categories starting with J appears, all other is not displayed. 
Is it possible? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Take a look at the [jQuery Show/Hide functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

Comment: No, this is not what I want, I misspoke, for example I have 20 categories on a page, I created a line with all the letters of the alphabets, when I click on the letter A, I have a new page with all categories starting with A. 
The url where all categories "http://website.com" when I click on the letter A, I have the url "http://website.com/a/" and all categories starting by A appears on the new page. 
I hope you understand me, sorry I'm french and google translate translates hurt.

Comment: This link should get you started: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-categories-that-start-with-a-certain-letter

Comment: No, I want to do exactly as this site with categories: "http://www.universalmusic.com/artists", when I click on the letter G, I am redirected to a page with all categories starting with G. 
I want to do exactly the same thing, it's possible?
Thank you.